# Configuring IPv6 automatically and IPv4 statically

Tags: linux, networking, ipv6, network-interface

I've got a Ubuntu Linux box that has two IPv4 addresses and an IPv6 address. This is my current `/etc/network/interfaces`:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0 eth0:0

iface eth0 inet static
        address 66.228.38.512
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        gateway 66.228.38.1

iface eth0:0 inet static
        address 192.168.171.512
        netmask 255.255.128.0
```

I want to add the IPv6 address (2600:3c03::c0a8/128, a few octets removed) to `eth0` so that it's autoconfigured. However, adding a sub-interface `eth0:1` and entering `iface eth0:1 inet6 autoconf` didn't work:

```
/etc/network/interfaces:15: unknown method
ifdown: couldn't read interfaces file "/etc/network/interfaces"
```

Is there a way that I can auto-configure IPv6 and statically configure IPv4 on the same interface?

<sub>*The .512 is just for obfuscation; the IPv4 IPs are fine.</sub>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem. Apparently, UFW (my front-end for `iptables`) was not set to be configured for IPv6. Setting `IPV6=no` to `IPV6=yes` in `/etc/default/ufw` solved the problem and allowed IPv6 autoconfiguration.